# popen в windows и пробелы

Tags: c++, c, windows

Убил достаточно большое количество времени, но так и не смог найти самостоятельно ответ на вопрос, посему решил обратиться за помощью в сообщество. Сразу скажу, IDE - Visual Studio 2019, работаю под Windows 10.
Суть вопроса такова: имеем 2 приложения и желание сделать а-ля pipe.

**Первое приложение - test1:**

```
/** \brief Это тестовый модуль, вызываемый через popen */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    /** \brief Просто вывожу все аргументы */
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("argv[%d] - %s\n", i, argv[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Второе приложение - test2:**

```
/** \brief Это тестовый модуль для проверки работы popen */
int main()
{
    /** \brief Формирование строки для запуска внешнего модуля */
    char buffer[2048];
    auto mProgram = "F:/Super Test/test1/test1.exe";
    sprintf(buffer, "\"%s\"", mProgram);

    /** \brief Запуск программы */
    auto pipe = _popen(buffer, "r");

    /** \brief Перехват stdout */
    std::array<char, 128> words;
    while (fgets(words.data(), words.size(), pipe) != nullptr) {
        std::cout << words.data();
    }
}
```

Запускаю test2 - все отлично, получаем то, что и ждём.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А теперь я хочу, чтобы в test1 приходил путь к файлу, который мне нужно обработать и ключ -in по которому я буду это понимать. Добавляю параметр mFile и меняю строку, передаваемую в *_popen*:

```
auto mProgram = "F:/Super Test/test1/test1.exe";
auto mFile = "F:/Super Test/test1/CMakeLists.txt";
sprintf(buffer, "\"%s\" -in %s", mProgram, mFile);
```

**Запускаем test2 еще раз:**

[image: второй запуск]

Видим не то, что мы хотели получить, но оно и правильно, ведь кавычки то я не поставил, а мы знаем как командная строка windows реагирует на пробелы...

Корректируем строчку:

`sprintf(buffer, "\"%s\" -in \"%s\"", mProgram, mFile);`

и **запускаем еще разок**

[image: Третий запуск]

На этом наши полномочия всё! (с)
Который час пытаюсь решить этот вопрос, но тщетно. Пытался вручную через cmd проводить данные операции, там все нормально. С _popen (да и с system, чего скрывать), ничего не выходит. Конечно, можно удалить пробел в названии папки и все будет прекрасно, но этот вариант меня не устраивает)
Объясните, люди добрые, в чем проблема, где же зарыта эта собака!?

Comment: Попробуйте удвоить слеши перед кавычками в строке -- `sprintf(buffer, "\"%s\\\" -in \\\"%s\"", mProgram, mFile);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При выполнении popen в качестве интерпретатора по-умолчанию запускается `cmd /c` после чего идет строка, переданная в popen. У cmd хитрое поведение при разборе кавычек:

> If /C or /K is specified, then the remainder of the command line after
> the switch is processed as a command line, where the following logic is
> used to process quote (") characters:
>
> 1. If all of the following conditions are met, then quote characters
>    on the command line are preserved:
>
> - no /S switch
> - exactly two quote characters
> - no special characters between the two quote characters,
>   where special is one of: &<>()@^|
> - there are one or more whitespace characters between the
>   two quote characters
> - the string between the two quote characters is the name
>   of an executable file.
>
> 2. Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is
>    a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and
>    remove the last quote character on the command line, preserving
>    any text after the last quote character.

Сооветсвенно решение - еще одна пара кавычек:

```
sprintf(buffer, R"(""%s" "-in" "%s"")", mProgram, mFile);
```

Ну и тут я еще использую raw string literal, чтобы снизить количество крякозябр.

PS Советую использовать boost.process, там можно передать пачку аргументов посредством `boost::process::args` не заботясь о пробелах и кавычках.

Comment: Т.е.  по сути надо удвоить начальные и конечные кавычки и заключать в кавычки пробелы между аргументами?

Comment: @avp Нет, кавычки в начале и в конце обрамляют команду, а в команде еще каждый аргумент обрамляется парой кавычек. `"-in"` можно было бы без кавычек, там пробела же нет.

Comment: Понятно. Аргументы в которых *могут быть пробелы* надо заключать в кавычки (если их там нет, то хуже не будет) (и надеяться что в этих аргументах нет кавычек -)) (и не забыть всю строку тоже закавычить)

Comment: Большое спасибо! Изучив повнимательнее cmd /? благодаря ответу и поигравшись с сочетаниями пришло полное просветление!

Comment: Буст я не очень люблю из-за размера и излишнего усложнения многих решений и стараюсь искать более легковесные точечные решения. boost::process никогда не использовал, но в данном случае, наверное, это и вправду куда лучше решение